# How to use svg sprites in next.js project

Tags: next.js, svg-sprite

I would like to use an svg sprite for the icons of my next.js app. Are there any articles on the best practices and how to implement them with compatibility to server side rendering?

I stumbled upon this package https://github.com/cyrilwanner/next-optimized-images#sprite and it's canary project, but it seems discontinued after the new next 10 and it's image optimizations.

If anyone has any successful implementations, and they would like to share, I would appreciate that.

Best Regards.